# How to add input fields dynamically in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to add input fields to array of objects and a map which grows dynamically based on user's choice.

For e.g. `InputForm` has a list and a map which needs to be filled by user.

```
export class InputForm {
  mapA: {};
  listA: ListA[] = [];
}

export class ListA {
    input1 : String
    input2 : number
}
```

I need to show it on UI in such a way that input1, input2 and key, value for map of criteria is visible as the input field. The user fills all 4 input fields and clicks on the add button.

Then again same input fields should be editable for the user for the second input. This way he can build list and map and when he clicks on submit button array and map should have all the values filled before.

`*ngFor` doesn't work because the initial list is empty.

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you are using [Angular Reactive Form](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms), you can use a combination of `*ngFor` and `FormArray`. You can start with an empty `FormArray` and add dynamically using the `.push()` method.

Here is a [good and detailed example](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields)

```ts
// order-form.component.ts:

@Component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: './order-form.component.html'
})
export class OrderFormComponent implements OnInit{
  orderForm: FormGroup;
  items: FormArray;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.orderForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      customerName: '',
      email: '',
      items: this.formBuilder.array([ this.createItem() ])
    });
  }

  createItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      name: '',
      description: '',
      price: ''
    });
  }

  addItem(): void {
    this.items = this.orderForm.get('items') as FormArray;
    this.items.push(this.createItem());
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- order-form.component.html -->

<div formArrayName="items"
  *ngFor="let item of orderForm.get('items').controls; let i = index;">
  <div [formGroupName]="i">
    <input formControlName="name" placeholder="Item name">
    <input formControlName="description" placeholder="Item description">
    <input formControlName="price" placeholder="Item price">
  </div>

  Chosen name: {{ orderForm.controls.items.controls[i].controls.name.value }}
</div>
```

Comment: `ERROR Error: formArrayName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup
       directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).`