# Angular 7 add new fields to form

Tags: javascript, angular, addeventlistener, html-templates

I have a small form and when the user clicks on an element I want to display some more fields to the form. This action can be done multiple times. So my ideia is to have a separated html file with these fields to be appended to the form so  I got this

```
public showMoreFields(): void {
    const wrapper_div = document.getElementById("wrapper");
    const template = require("./my-template.html")

    container.innerHTML += template
}
```

The new fields are being appended properly.

My **first question** is: Is this the best approach to load external html? (I don't have the "text/template" script tag)

Or should I create a new component and append it to the maim form?

```
....
<input type="text" .... />
<my-new-fields></my-new-fields>
...
<button></button>
```

If so, how do I append new ones?

Also read about [`ngTemplateOutlet`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet#description) but didn't figure out how can apply to my case. 
I am quite confused about this

**Second**. Although my new fields are being displayed the click events they are not triggering my functions.

exemple:

```
<span class="fa fa-remove" (click)="cleanInput()"></span>
// this is not executing the cleanInput function
```

Thanks

Comment: No. It's a horrible idea. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54521848/how-to-add-input-fields-dynamically-in-angular-6

Comment: You must use reactive form. Have a look at this article this may help you. https://blog.karmacomputing.co.uk/angular-6-dynamically-add-rows-reactive-forms-how-to/

Answer (score 0):

You can use *ngIf or [hidden] attributes on the section which you want to hide.

Example:

```
<input [(ngModel)] = "model1">
<your-component *ngIf="areExtraFieldsVisible">
</your-component>
<button (click)="showExtraFields()"></button>
```

Comment: But I can have multiple fields. so I will need to append <your-compoenent> dynamically

Answer (score 0):

1,
you can use flag in your component to show/hide data on button click:

in component:

```
showData: boolean = false;
```

in html:

```
    <button (click)="this.showData=!this.showData">show/hide</button>

    <div *ngIf="this.showData">
        ...
    </div>
```

Comment: Its not a single group of fields. The user can add multiple times that group of fields

Comment: use a list component, which contains a `formArray` and you can add `formGroup` to `formArray`. List component contains component which contains `formGroup` fields.